# randomly sum values in pandas column and plot them

Tags: python

I have a dataset that predicts the return of 300 stocks. Each row is an observation with response either 0 or 1 if it was predicted to have negative or positive return, and also the actual precent return in a 'return' column. I want to select 50 of these 300 predictions 300 times and plot what the returns would be. I have so far

```
df_p = pd.read_csv("portfolio.csv")

list = []
for i in 300:
    df_portfolio = df_p.sample(n=50)
    return = df_p['return'].sum()
    list.append(return)

plt.plot(list[:])
plt.show()
```

but i get error. I am not that good in Python so would appreciate help

Comment: `return` is a [reserved word](https://realpython.com/lessons/reserved-keywords/) in python and it should not be used as a variable or function name.

Comment: @MohamedSayed as well as list

Comment: Although it's not a good practice I can write `list = []` and python won't object. @AmineBTG

Answer (score 0):

You should not use list nor return as a variable names as they are both special python key words.
Try the below:

```py
df_p = pd.read_csv("portfolio.csv")

results_list = []
for i in 300:
    df_portfolio = df_p.sample(n=50)
    results_list.append(df_portfolio['return'].sum())
    

plt.plot(results_list)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_p = pd.read_csv("portfolio.csv")

values = []
for i in 300:
    df_portfolio = df_p.sample(n=50)
    val = df_portfolio['return'].sum()
    values.append(val)

plt.plot(y=values, x=range(1,len(values)+1)
plt.show()
```

- Don't use reserved keywords as a parameters